# How do I transfer the actual value of [object Object] to an input field

Tags: jquery

A page has a playscript in a php included file: (the playscript has hundreds of lines)

With php I've manipulated the playscript to contain certain tags
    `<lineNo1>, <charName1> and <dialogue1>`

Using `<?php echo $i;$i++;?>`, I've incremented the whole script so it has 25 Lessons, each with 10 lines of dialogue, and each line of dialogue displays those parameters correctly, i.e.:

```
<div id="dialogue">
<div id="1">
<Lesson1>Lesson 1</Lesson1>
<lineNo1>1</lineNo1>) <charName1>Sherry</charName1>
<dialogue1>Look at this, I'm shaking.</dialogue1></div></div>
```

All that php works great through 250 iterations, but my jquery skills are nascent and my script is bogus.

On click of `<Insert>Insert</Insert>`, I need to transfer the text values, i.e. '1', 'Sherry' and 'Look...shaking.' from inside the tags to form text input fields,
 LIne, Speaker and LIneX:

```
<div id="LessonNumber1">
<div id="LineNumber1">
<input type="text" name="Line" id="Line" value="" />
<input type="text" name="Speaker" id="Speaker" value="" />
<input type="text" name="LineX" id="LineX" value="" />
</div></div>
```

My jquery script, below, works partially. The first input text field, 'Line' is receiving the (`<?php echo $LineItem;?>`).text; value perfectly, for obvious reasons. 
But the other fields are receiving [object Object]; all my research on [object Object] has led me in circles, ultimately here.
Will someone please tell me how to re-write the last two lines, for #Speaker and #LineX so that the actual values will appear in the form fields instead of [object Object]?

`<script type="text/javascript">`
`$(document).ready(function(){`
`$("Insert").click(function(){`
`$("#TheForm #LessonNumber<?php echo $LineItem;?> #LineNumber<?php echo $LineItem;#Line").val(<?php echo $LineItem;?>).text();`

These last two are examples of my problem.
`$("#TheForm #LessonNumber1 #LineNumber1 #Speaker").val("what goes here if not <charName1></charName1>").val();`
`$("#TheForm #LessonNumber1 #LineNumber1 #LineX").val("what goes here if not <dialogue1></dialogue1>").text();});});</script>`

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post a piece of code representing your problem to jsfiddle? It will be helpful. Right now it's pretty hard to figure out what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**val** and **text** are functions, you must add () to call them and get their results. If you
juste write **val** or **text**, it's the reference to the function itself (and in js, a function is an object).

```
myfield.val( mytext.text() );
```

this will set the value of input field 'myfield' with the text inside the element 'mytext'

Try to do the same in your code

```
$("#TheForm #LessonNumber1 #LineNumber1 #Speaker").val( $('your_selector').text() );
```

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected my oversights per your notes. The [object Object] disappeared but nothing appears in the input form yet. I'm examining my selectors but I think I have them correctly.

Comment: Thanks Marcha and pxx. Tweaks later, it is working as desired. As a nube, I had too many different concepts working against each other. Simply following your snip really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I really tried to get into your problem, but I can't understand that crazy mixture of HTML and XML. Why don't you use basic HTML tags?

I only can point out some syntax issues in your code. Maybe it will help you.

1. First `val` argument has no quotes. Should be: `.val("what goes here if not <charName1></charName1>")`.
2. Second val is used as a property but not as function. Should be: `.val();`

Comment: Thanks for the syntax note. Why don't you use basic HTML tags? I've swapped back and forth, no joy. Also, cause I'm not very good, hence my questions.